# Use of concatrelated vba excel

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I'm having problem using the function concatrelated on a sql statement. I want to obtain as follows:

My data is:

```
A.CABNRO E01.EXCCEX
90001 500
87000 400
90001 450
90001 300
87000 500
76005
```

I want to obtain:

```
A.CABNRO NEW FIELD
90001 500,450,300
87000 400,500
76005
```

The following code does not run when I include the statement related with concatrelated. I will be grateful if someone can help me!!!

```
MYSQL = "SELECT A.CABFPR, A.CABCIA, A.CABCTR, B.CTRDTR, A.CABLOE, "
MYSQL = MYSQL & "A.CABNRO, A.CABCAR, A.CABFED, A.CABHOD, A.CABFEI, "
MYSQL = MYSQL & "A.CABHOI, A.CABFEF, A.CABHOF, A.CABFEE, A.CABHOE, "
MYSQL = MYSQL & "A.CABCCL, A.CABNEM, A.CABDEM "
MYSQL = MYSQL & "CONCATRELATED(EXCCEX, E01, A.CABNRO=E01.EXCNRO) "
MYSQL = MYSQL & "FROM BDYOBEL.AIPDTA.AIPCAB A "
MYSQL = MYSQL & "LEFT OUTER JOIN BDYOBEL.AIPDTA.AIPCTR B ON A.CABCIA=B.CTRCIA AND A.CABCTR=B.CTRCTR "
MYSQL = MYSQL & "LEFT OUTER JOIN BDYOBEL.AIPDTA.AIPEXC E01 ON A.CABNRO=E01.EXCNRO "
MYSQL = MYSQL & "WHERE A.CABCIA='LOR' AND A.CABFED>="
MYSQL = MYSQL & Chr$(39) & fini & Chr$(39) & "AND A.CABFED<=" & Chr$(39) & ffin & Chr$(39)
MYSQL = MYSQL & " AND (A.CABCTR='DM' OR A.CABCTR='L1' OR A.CABCTR='L5' OR A.CABCTR='LR') AND A.CABCAR<>'0'"
```

Comment: You're selecting a lot more than your sample data implies.

Answer (score 0):

On http://allenbrowne.com/func-concat.html is stated

> If the ConcatRelated function returns more than 255 characters, and
>   you use it in a query as the source for another recordset, a bug in
>   Access may return garbage for the remaining characters.

This might explain why your code is not working.
Aggregating data for an non-fixed number of columns can not be achieved in Access. The best you can do is write something like this and combine the columns with a text editor.

```
TRANSFORM Sum(E01.EXCCEX) AS SumOfEXCCEX
SELECT A.CABNRO
FROM [BDYOBEL-AIPDTA-AIPCAB] AS A INNER JOIN [BDYOBEL-AIPDTA-AIPEXC] AS E01 ON 
  A.CABNRO = E01.EXCNRO
GROUP BY A.CABNRO
ORDER BY A.CABNRO DESC , E01.EXCCEX DESC 
PIVOT E01.EXCCEX;
```

Running the query gives the following result for your example data:
[image: screenshot of access output].